# How can I structure a try/catch with a variable definition

Tags: c#, json, try-catch, json.net, deserialization

Writing in C# and I'm getting JSONReaderExceptions here:

```
var container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HistoryResponseContainer> (responseData);
```

It's always something like a unterminated line or unrecognized character.

I know I need to catch and throw these errors, but it breaks if I try and define "container" inside a try/catch statement. Here's the whole method.

```
foreach (String StationID in StationIDList) { 

            string url = @"http://api.wunderground.com/api/" + wundergroundkey + "/history_" + Date + "/q/pws:" + StationID + ".json";
            Uri uri = new Uri (url);
            WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create (uri);
            WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse ();
            StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader (response.GetResponseStream ());
            String responseData = streamReader.ReadToEnd ();

            var container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HistoryResponseContainer> (responseData);

            foreach (var observation in container.history.observations) {

                CurrentData.Write (StationID + " ");
                // This makes easier access to the date. not perfect, but better.
                DateTime date = observation.date.Value;
                DateTime utc = observation.utcdate.Value;

                // whatever you want to do with each observation
                if (date.Minute == 0 || date.Minute % 5 == 0) {
                    CurrentData.Write (date.Hour + ":" + date.Minute + " " + observation.wdird + " " + observation.wspdi);
                }//end if

                CurrentData.Write ("\n");

            } //End foreach observation

        } //end foreach station
```

Comment: What do you mean by it pukes ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your second foreach loop inside try (because you're using your "container"). Otherwise it won't be defined if an exception is raised and you only "try/catch" your container instanciation:

```
foreach (String StationID in StationIDList) 
{ 
    string url = @"http://api.wunderground.com/api/" + wundergroundkey + "/history_" + Date + "/q/pws:" + StationID + ".json";
    Uri uri = new Uri (url);
    WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create (uri);
    WebResponse response = webRequest.GetResponse ();
    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader (response.GetResponseStream ());
    String responseData = streamReader.ReadToEnd ();

    try
    {
        var container = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<HistoryResponseContainer> (responseData);

        foreach (var observation in container.history.observations) 
        {
            CurrentData.Write (StationID + " ");
            DateTime date = observation.date.Value;
            DateTime utc = observation.utcdate.Value;

            if (date.Minute == 0 || date.Minute % 5 == 0) 
            {
                CurrentData.Write (date.Hour + ":" + date.Minute + " " + observation.wdird + " " + observation.wspdi);
            }

            CurrentData.Write ("\n");

        }
    }
    catch(JsonReaderException ex)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I know I need to catch and throw these errors,

No you need just catch and handle these errors.

> but it pukes if I try and define "container" inside a try/catch statement.

What do you mean here ? You need this:

```
try
{
   // your code that throws exception
}
catch(JsonReaderException ex)
{
   // handle your exception
}
```